# Referencing creates double entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

In my setup I have an Entity "Appointment" with a related entity "Trainer" with where 1 Appointment is related to 1 Trainers but 1 Trainer can be assigned to n Appointments. The creation of trainers works as expected. After creating the appointments the count of trainers is doubled. I assume that the referencing between Appointment and Trainer is wrong. Any ideas?

Btw, I followed [SQLiteCodeFirst](https://github.com/msallin/SQLiteCodeFirst/issues) for the model creation. (should have no effect here, I assume).

Trainer:

```
[Table("Trainer")]

public class Trainer : IEntity
{
    [Autoincrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Appointment:

```
[Table("Appointment")]
public class Appointment 
{
    [Autoincrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Trainer Trainer { get; set; } 
}
```

My dummy value creation:

```
 context.Set<Trainer>().Add(new Trainer {Name = "Max Mustermann"});
 context.Set<Trainer>().Add(new Trainer {Name = "Fritze Bollmann"});
 context.Set<Trainer>().Add(new Trainer {Name = "Andi Mauer"});
 context.SaveChanges();

 List<Trainer> trainers = Trainers(); //here the count of trainers is correct
 //do this 100 times:
 Random gen = new Random();
 int t = gen.Next(trainers.Count);
 appointment.Trainer = trainers[t];
 context.SaveChanges();

 // here the count of trainers is wrong

 public static List<Trainer> Trainers()
 {
      using (var context = new PDEDbContext(DbName))
      {
          return context.Set<Trainer>().ToList();
      }
 }
```

Comment: How can the appointment be related to n trainers when 1 appointment have 1 trainer, as a property?

Comment: yes, changed it.

Comment: When adding the appointment with trainer, you also add the trainer (because it's a new object). Either set the state of the trainer object to detached/unchanged/modified, only set the FK (without navigation property) or set the property after attaching the objects to the context.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro I don't intent to add the trainer as a new Object. Where exactly am I doing it? Could you give code for your solutions?

Comment: `List<Trainer> trainers = Trainers(); ` is incorrect, it will give you compilation error